# Detecting if a div above has margin in CSS?

Tags: css

I currently have two elements:

```
.item-one {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
..other-elements..
.item-two {
    margin-top: 48px;
}
```

These items are fine on their own, but say, if I removed the `..other elements..` between them, so they'd be one after another, I would be left with a total margin (visually) of 72px.

The `..other elements..` have a consistent 24px, because of the flow, but my app is dynamic and users can switch places of elements.

Unfortunately, this is highly undesirable as it'd result in bad looking spaces.

I'd like to write something like

```
.item-two [if-div-is-previous -> .item-one] {
    //this will set the margin to 0 only if preceded by .item-one
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

**In short, I'm trying to keep a consistent distance between all the elements on the page of 24 px, even when items that have different margins than 24px are one after another.**

Comment: Obviously the "other elements" play a part in this and there is no way to help without knowing what is going on there.

Comment: @Rob The "+" works. .item-one + item-two {} allows me to see if the items are next to each other and change their properties if true :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.item-one + .item-two {  } //if .item-two is next to .item-one
```

Comment: This will work only with the immediatly adjacent element. If you have more adjacent elements it won't affect them.

Comment: Correct. It's exactly what I want! Additionally, I discovered that using only margin-top and then padding-bottom to generate my spaces usually yields a better result and I don't have to write as many rules (so no layout trashing as much).

Comment: @Adren Do you know how I can add a third parameter such as .item-one + .item-two |another-item-here| ? So if item-one is followed by item-two, the changes will be made to the next selector?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how margins work. CSS have vertical collapsing margins.
You're margins will always be 24px, not 48. As long as the two are adjacents and in the same formating context.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

EDIT: with the information you added I understand that your problem is that the following adjacent elements may have bigger margin. You can reset them with the `~` following selector

```
#one~*{
  margin-top: 24px !important;
  margin-bottom: 24px !important;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VMzwvq

Comment: Sorry, this was not at all what my question was about, can you tell me where you understood it this way so I can fix, maybe? // I understand this is how it works, but I'd like one of the elements to change their margin if the other one is next to them.

Comment: That's not what you asked, you said you want "consistent distance between all elements". That is already what is happening naturally. This codepen illustrate it : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzjPwB

Comment: Just saw you reformulated your question, I have edited my initial answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the other guy provided the "+" which works marvellously. I'm not exactly sure where I went wrong with the explanation.